# Previously tested Regex is not working now, but works in Regex Tester

Tags: c#, .net, regex, visual-studio, .net-4.5

I have the following:

```
        var exp = new Regex("(.+):(.+)-(.+)");
        var matches = exp.Matches("AR1:CP1-CP2");
```

When I go to http://regexstorm.net/tester this works:

[image]

And I'm certain I had some test code which was working... but now when I run it in my C# application (this is exact code above) I get a single match, the input string, and my later code then crashes.

[image]

I'm coding today on VS 2015 rather than VS2013 which I wrote the code with but other than that I'm at a loss. Can anyone figure this out?

Comment: I would suggest changing the regex to `([^:]+):([^-]+)-(.+)` to avoid back-tracking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you get a single match. The regex only matches once. The match itself, however, has three groups (four, counting the whole match, which is implicitly group 0):

```
PS Home:\> [regex]::matches('AR1:CP1-CP2', '(.+):(.+)-(.+)')


Groups   : {AR1:CP1-CP2, AR1, CP1, CP2}
Success  : True
Captures : {AR1:CP1-CP2}
Index    : 0
Length   : 11
Value    : AR1:CP1-CP2
```

Comment: I'm so confused then how my code was working before. Unless I have really nerdy dreams and dreamt I finished my code... but it's been checked in for months! Weird...

Comment: I have this whole class which I have strong memories of testing but it doesn't work and I am at a loss what has happened...

Comment: Well, I can assure you that regex behaviour in this regard did not change in any .NET version ;-)